# How can I play a decimal frequency?

Tags: python, frequency

How can I play decimal frequencies in winsound such as 40.248?

For example:

```
import winsound  
winsound.Beep(90.47856,1000)
```

Also, how can I play two sounds simultaneously (at the same time)?

Answer (score 1):

`winsound.Beep` is a simple wrapper for the Windows [`Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which only takes integer arguments. You're not going to be able to play fractional frequencies with that. It also doesn't support simultaneous sounds.

If you want to use `winsound` (which is an extremely simple wrapper for the Windows API), you could generate wave data by hand and use the `winsound.PlaySound` function.

Comment: `The frequency parameter specifies frequency, in hertz, of the sound, and must be in the range 37 through 32,767.` there are different information in the official docs

Comment: @Laszlowaty: Doesn't change the fact that in the semi-official implementation it is a wrapper for a function that doesn't take fractional arguments. Read the source: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/PC/winsound.c#l114

Comment: @Laszlowaty: I guess the documentation could be more accurate and say that (at least in actual implementations) the parameter is converter to an integer. But then again how often does somebody need to beep the PC speaker in 2016...?

Comment: Well that's true, but I think that docs should be more accurate. However now I'm not sure that comma in the "32,767" is the decimal seperator or not.

Comment: @Laszlowaty - 32767 = 2^15 - 1. It seems unlikely that it is a decimal separator, especially since the lower bound of the range (37) would be greater than the upper bound (~33).

Comment: @Laszlowaty: I don't think they'd ever use a comma as a decimal separator in the Python docs since they're written in English. Plus the language itself uses the correct ".".